# Assistance: "Two functions, prove uniform conv. using sup-norm"

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

I hope everything is going well.

I am interested in demonstrating that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in B \subseteq [0,\infty)$ the following
$$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^n} \text{ and } g_n(x) = \begin{cases}1,&\text{if $x \geq \frac{1}{n}$}\\nx,&\text{ if $0\leq x < \frac{1}{n}$} \end{cases}$$
converge uniformly on $B$. I am tasked with using the **sup-norm** for this. More specifically, I want to make use of the theorem

> A sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, with $f_n : A \to \mathbb{R}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, converges to $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly on $B \subseteq A$ if $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\Vert f_n - f\Vert_{\infty;B}= 0$

**Some Thoughts**

I am thinking for $f_n(x)$ to consider $x \in [0,1)$ and for $g_n(x)$ to consider $x \in [0,\frac{1}{n})$. Additionally, for $f_n(x)$, I am inclined to think that since
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \bigg| \frac{x}{1+x^n} - 0 \bigg|< x^n < \frac{1}{n}  $$
we have
$$ 0 \leq \underset{x\in [0,1)}{\text{sup}}|f_n(x) -f(x)| < \frac{1}{n}$$
which along with the Squeeze Theorem could give us that $f_n(x)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Any assistance would be much appreciated! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is  not correct, note that $\lim_{h \to \infty}f_h(x) = x$ for every
$x \in [0,1)$
$$\Big|\frac{x}{1 + x^h} - x\Big| = \Big|\frac{-x^{h + 1}}{1 + x^h} \Big| \geq \frac{x^{h + 1}}{2}$$
Passing to the supremum we have
$$\sup_{x \in [0,1)}|f_h(x) - x| \geq \frac{1}{2}$$
for every $h \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore $(f_h)_h$ cannot converges uniformly.

For the second function I will consider $g_h : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, note that each function is continuous. Let us calculate the pointwise limit:
$$\lim_{h \to \infty}g_h(0) = 0$$
Note that for every $x \in (0,1]$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} \leq x$ so that $g_n(x) = 1$ for every $n \geq N$, which gives
$$\lim_{h \to \infty}g_h(x) = 1$$
We have proved that the sequence $(g_h)_h$ converges pointwise to the discontinuous function
$$g(x) := \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{if } x = 0\\
                        1 & \mbox{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$
As a consequence the convergence cannot be uniform

Note that even if we exclude the point $0$ form the domain the convergence is still not uniform, indeed:
$$|g_h(x) -1 | = \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{if } x \geq \frac{1}{h}\\
                        hx & \mbox{if } x \in (0,\frac{1}{h}) 
\end{cases}$$
So
$$\sup_{x \in (0,1]}|g_h(x) - 1| = 1$$
for every $h \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Is there no subset of $[0, \infty)$ where $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly?

Comment: @rodeo_flagellum Try with $[a,\infty)$ with $a>1$, of course the limit function is different now

Comment: @rodeo_flagellum $g_n(x)$ converges uniformly on any $[a,\infty)$ for $a > 0$

Comment: Nice, one more thing, can you please explain the reasoning behind this remark: "As a consequence the convergence cannot be uniform". I will most likely check your answer, but I will wait so that others are more motivated to respond as well.

Comment: @rodeo_flagellum Beacuse the uniform limit of continuous functions is still continuous and $g$ is clearly not continuous:)

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand now. Thank you for your assistance! I wish you the best and may our paths cross digitally again!

Comment: @rodeo_flagellum You are welcome! I wish you the best too:)